# make json array in json codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

please help, i got stucked on making json using codeigniter.

this is what i want my json look like

[image]

```
{
  "pelajar": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "rumah sakit",
      "usia": "45",
      "tahun": "2020",
      "alamat": "jalan kartini"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "rumah sakit umum",
      "usia": "28",
      "tahun": "2020",
      "alamat": "jalan ibu",
      "pendidikan": [
        {
          "id_pelajar": "2",
          "sekolah": "SDN Lombok timur"
        },
        {
          "id_pelajar": "2",
          "sekolah": "SMPN Lombok timur"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

but, i dont know why my code doesnt work to make like it.

this is how my code output :
[image]

```
{
  "pelajar": {
    "pelajar": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "rumah sakit",
        "usia": "45",
        "tahun": "2020",
        "alamat": "jalan kartini"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "rumah sakit umum",
        "usia": "28",
        "tahun": "2020",
        "alamat": "jalan ibu"
      }
    ],
    "pendidikan": [
      {
        "id_pelajar": "2",
        "sekolah": "SDN Lombok timur"
      },
      {
        "id_pelajar": "2",
        "sekolah": "SMPN Lombok timur"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

this is my code :

```
$query = $this->db->query("select * from learn") -> result();
        $response = array();
        $data = array();
        $datap = array();

        foreach($query as $row){

            $data[] = array(
                    "id"=> $row->id,
                    "name"=>$row->name,
                    "usia"=>$row->usia,
                    "tahun"=>$row->tahun,
                    "alamat"=>$row->alamat

            );

            $id = $row->id;
            $pendidikanquery = $this->db->query("select * from pendidikan where learn_id='$id'" ) -> result();
            foreach($pendidikanquery as $pen){
                $datap[] = array(
                    "id_pelajar"=> $pen->id_pelajar,
                    "sekolah"=> $pen->sekolah
                );
            }


            }
        }

        $response['pelajar']['pelajar'] = $data;
        $response['pelajar']['pendidikan'] = $datap;

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response, TRUE);
```

my problem is to set 'pendidikan' in the pelajar list where id_pelajar from pendidikan is same with id from pelajar table.

Comment: You should be using JOIN not nested queries.  If you are using CI, I recommend ActiveRecord to make your queries portal/secure/stable.

Comment: @Tajniak i've edit in post

Comment: @mickmackusa JOIN by MySql?

Comment: @Tajniak the JSON format is in the post too bro.

Comment: @Tajniak can you explain what desired output look like? i'm still learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, there is so much to fix, this script should probably be completely rewritten, but I am not prepared to do that from my phone.

I would recommend using Active Record techniques in your model (not your controller).

Cache the subarray data before pushing into the first level. In doing so, you maintain the relationship between the parent id and the subarray data.

To be clear, my snippet will always create a `pendidikan` subarray -- even if it has no data.  If you do not want this behavior, you will need to modify the script to check if the subarray is empty and then conditionally include it into the parent array.  If this was my project, I would prefer a consistent data structure so that subsequent process wouldn't need to check again if specific keys exist.

Untested code:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM learn")->result();
$data = [];
foreach($query as $row){
    $datap = [];
    $pendidikanquery = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM pendidikan WHERE learn_id = {$row->id}")->result();
    foreach ($pendidikanquery as $pen) {
        $datap[] = [
            "id_pelajar" => $pen->id_pelajar,
            "sekolah" => $pen->sekolah
        ];
    }
    $data[] = [
        "id" => $row->id,
        "name" => $row->name,
        "usia" => $row->usia,
        "tahun" => $row->tahun,
        "alamat" => $row->alamat,
        "pendidikan" => $datap
    ];
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(["pelajar" => $data]);
```

Comment: Although this answer resolves the asked question, half of this answer is implementing techniques that I would not use in a professional project.  There should not be iterated trips to the database; there should be a single database query which involves a JOIN clause.  Querying should be done in the model, not in the controller.

Answer (score -1):

if you want the output like your first image(the one with a red square)-

```
$response['pelajar']['pendidikan'] = $datap; // change this one to
// this ↓↓
$response['pelajar']['pelajar']['pendidikan'] = $datap; // change it like this
```

Comment: This answer is missing its explanation.  If the question is unclear, please do not answer.

Comment: This solution will not be enough because the OP is disassociating the parent row ids from the subquery data.